# Change div display depending on a select in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this dropdown:

```
<select>
    <option value='CAD'>CAD</option>
    <option value='USD'>USD</option>
    <option value='MXN'>MXN</option>
</select>

<div id="currency-alert" class="hide">My alert message</div>
```

I want to have the possibility to show t div depending the user selection.

So I used:

```
if(currency != 'CAD') { 
    $('#currency-alert').toggleClass('show', 'hide'); 
}else{ 
    $('#currency-alert').toggleClass('hide', 'show'); 
}
```

Problem is, when I select USD and after MXN, the box desaperes.

How can I change this please ?

The box should display only for USD and MXN but not for CAD.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the second parameter on `toggleClass`? Where is the `#currency-alert`?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: `#currency-alert` is my div containing the alert message.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the `div` only for `CAD` the just use `show` to show it and `hide` when the other currency is selected.

```
if(currency != 'CAD') { 
    $('#currency-alert').show(); 
}else{ 
    $('#currency-alert').hide(); 
}
```

If you don't want to show it at start up you can initialize it with `display:none`

Comment: At the start the `div` has the class `hide`.